# Prove that $\mathbf{FinSets}^{\mathbf{N}}$ has no subobject classifier.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, functors

This is **Exercise I.2** of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's, *"Sheaves in Geometry and Logic [. . .]."*

### The Question:

> Prove that $\mathbf{FinSets}^{\mathbf{N}}$ has no subobject classifier.

Here $\mathbf{FinSets}$ is the category of objects all finite sets and arrows all functions between them. We denote by $\mathbf{N}$ the linearly ordered set of natural numbers.

A definition of a subobject classifier is given on page 32, *ibid.*

> **Definition:** In a category $\mathbf{C}$ with finite limits, a *subobject classifier* is a monic, ${\rm true}:1\to\Omega$, such that to every monic $S\rightarrowtail X$ in $\mathbf{C}$ there is a unique arrow $\phi$ which, with the given monic, forms a pullback square
>
> $$\begin{array}{ccc}
> S & \to & 1 \\
> \downarrow & \, & \downarrow {\rm true}\\
> X & \stackrel{\dashrightarrow}{\phi} & \Omega.
> \end{array}$$

### Thoughts:

I'm not sure what the terminal object of $\mathbf{FinSets}^{\mathbf{N}}$ is, if it exists at all. My guess is that it's the functor $1: \Bbb N\to \{\ast\}, n\mapsto \ast$ for the singleton set $\{\ast\}$ up to isomorphism but my suspicion is that this guess is way off.

My idea so far is to take some monic $S\stackrel{f}{\rightarrowtail}X$ in the category in question and show, somehow, that there is no such arrow as ${\rm true}: 1\to\Omega$ satisfying the definition. I don't know yet how to execute this idea.

### Further Context:

I have recently finished a light reading of Goldblatt's book, *"Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic"*. I have been interested in topoi for a good few years now. (See some of my very first questions on this site.)

I think, then, that I ought to be able to solve this myself. I'm keen to try out other questions, though, and this one is taking me too long.

Please help :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a standard trick using the Yoneda lemma for computing what universal objects in (restricted) functor categories must be *if they exist*. In the case of the subobject classifier, this is explained on p. 37 of *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*.

Specifically, suppose that $\Omega\colon \mathbf{N}\to \mathbf{FinSets}$ is a subobject classifier in $\mathbf{FinSets}^\mathbf{N}$. Let's try to find out what finite set $\Omega(0)$ is. Since $\mathbf{FinSets}^\mathbf{N}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathbf{Sets}^\mathbf{N}$, by Yoneda we have $$\Omega(0) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbf{Sets}^\mathbf{N}}(h^0,\Omega) = \text{Hom}_{\mathbf{FinSets}^\mathbf{N}}(h^0,\Omega) \cong \text{Sub}(h^0),$$ where $h^0$ is the functor $\text{Hom}_{\mathbf{N}}(0,-)$. But now $h^0$ has infinitely many subobjects, but $\Omega(0)$ is a finite set, and this is a contradiction.

To see that $h^0$ has infinitely many subobjects, just note that since $0$ is the initial object in $\mathbf{N}$, $h^0(n)$ is a singleton $\{*\}$ for all $n$. Incidentally, this makes $h^0$ isomorphic to the terminal object $1$ - your guess about the identity of terminal object is correct.

Now for each natural number $n$ (or $n = \infty$), there is a distinct subobject of $h^0$, given by $$m\mapsto \begin{cases} \varnothing & \text{if }m<n\\ \{*\} & \text{if }m\geq n.\end{cases}$$

Comment: So sorry for asking this but can you please explain more about $h^0$ be ing isomorphic to the terminal object in category of finite sets and also defining distinct subobjects of $h^0$? I don't know what kind of things are subobjects of $h^0$?

Comment: @user850424 I'm happy to explain more, but you'll have to tell me what you don't understand about what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I don't understand it because I have no idea of sub objects of $h^0$

Comment: @user850424 Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. $h^0$ is a functor. Do you understand what a subobject is in a category of functors?

Comment: It is a subfunctor right?

Comment: @user850424 Right. And in my answer, I wrote down infinitely many subfunctors of $h^0$.

Comment: Are these sub objects from $Hom(0,n)$ to $Hom(0,m)$ or some thing like this?

Comment: Or from natural numbers to $h^0$?

Comment: It seems like you are confused about what a subfunctor is. Here is the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfunctor

Comment: Oh, thanks, I think I got it.

Comment: Then $Sub(h^0)$ is infinite because there are infinitely many natural numbers greater than each $n$? Right?

Comment: @user850424 No. Fix a natural number $n$. Then I defined a subfunctor $F_n$ of $h^0$ by $$F_n(m) = \begin{cases} \varnothing & \text{if }m<n\\ \{*\} & \text{if }m\geq n.\end{cases}.$$ Since there are infinitely many natural numbers, this gives infinitely many elements of $Sub(h^0)$: $\{F_n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subseteq Sub(h^0)$.

Comment: Thank you. Really sorry for annoying..... this time I really got it.

Answer (score 3):

You are actually right that that the terminal object of your category is the constant functor at $\{∗\}$:  what is a morphism to the constant functor at $\{∗\}$? It is a general fact about functor categories: limits can be computed pointwise (if the limit exists pointwise, then it exists globally as a functor; but the converse is not true).

But actually, you can proceed like this without using which object is $1$: try to find an object $X$ such that for every possible $$, the number of arrows to $$ is *too small* to classify the subobjects of $X$. Write things down: fix $X = (X_1 → X_2 → X_3 → ⋯)$ and $ = (_1 → _2 → ⋯)$. What is an arrow from $X$ to $$? There is potentially lots of them. How can you make this quantity smaller without putting too much restriction on $X$?

Here is a further hint: think of the process of building an arrows $X→$ as follows. First choose an arrow $X_1→_1$, then an arrow $X_2→_2$ making the diagram commute, then $X_3→_3$, etc. How can you make it so that at each step, there is exactly one choice?

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding the Terminal Object:**

You are correct that $\newcommand\1{\mathbf{1}}$the terminal object is the constant functor $\1:n\mapsto \newcommand\set[1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}\set{*}$.

This is more generally true in any functor category $[C,D]$. If $D$ has a terminal object, $t$, then the constant functor $\Delta_t : c\mapsto t$ is a terminal object in $[C,D]$, since for any functor $F:C\to D$, there is a unique map $\alpha_c : Fc \to \Delta_t c= t$, since $t$ is a terminal object in $D$. You can check that $t$ being terminal also causes $\alpha$ to be natural.

**Note:**

The terminal object will prove to be irrelevant. It suffices to know that in our case, $\Omega$ (if it existed) would represent the subobject functor.

**Subobjects in $[\mathbb{N},\mathbf{FinSet}]$:**

Now we need to figure out what subobjects look like.
First observe that if a natural transformation $\alpha :F \to G$ is such that $\alpha_n$ is injective for all $n$, then it is a monomorphism. This is because if $\alpha\beta= \alpha\gamma$, then $\alpha_n\beta_n = \alpha_n\gamma_n$ for all $n$, and then since $\alpha_n$ is injective, $\beta_n=\gamma_n$ for all $n$. Therefore $\beta=\gamma$. I will call this property being a pointwise monomorphism.

**Note:**

This generalizes to general functor categories, pretty immediately.

**Aside, Pointwise Monomorphisms are equivalent to Monomorphisms in $[\mathbb{N},\mathbf{FinSet}]$:**

Consider the functor $(-)_n : [\newcommand\FinSet{\mathbf{FinSet}}\newcommand\NN{\mathbb{N}}\NN, \FinSet] \to \FinSet$ that sends $F$ to $Fn$, for $n\in\NN$. This functor has a left adjoint. For a set $A$, we define the functor $A_{\ge n}$, which sends $m$ to $\varnothing$ if $m < n$, and $m$ to $A$ if $m\ge n$. The vertical maps are the obvious ones (inclusion of $\varnothing$ into $A$ or the identities).
You can verify that
$$[\NN,\FinSet](A_{\ge n},F) \simeq \FinSet(A,(F)_n).$$

Thus the functor $(-)_n$ is a right adjoint, and therefore preserves monomorphisms.
Hence monomorphisms are pointwise monomorphisms in our category.

**Nonexistence of a Subobject Classifier:**

Suppose a subobject classifier $\1\to \Omega$ existed. Let $\newcommand\Sub{\operatorname{Sub}}\Sub:[\NN,\FinSet]^{\text{op}}\to\mathbf{Set}$ be the subobject functor.
Then $$[\NN,\FinSet](A_{\ge 0},\Omega) \simeq \FinSet(A,(\Omega)_0) \simeq \Sub(A_{\ge 0}).$$
Now the subobjects of $A_{\ge 0}$ are increasing chains of subsets of $A$ (regarded as functors in the obvious way). Let $\omega = \#(\Omega)_0$. Then if $A$ has cardinality $n$, $\#\FinSet(A,(\Omega)_0) = \omega^n$. I.e., the number of mappings have exponential growth in $n$. How about subobjects of $A_{\ge 0}$? Well a maximal chain of subsets of $A$ is equivalent to a permutation of $A$, so there are at least $n!$ subobjects of $A_{\ge 0}$. Thus the number of subobjects of $A_{\ge 0}$ grows faster than exponentially in the size of $A$. This is a contradiction.

**Note:**

We didn't actually need that monomorphisms were monomorphisms pointwise, which is why I called it an aside, but we did use that $(-)_0$ was right adjoint to $-_{\ge 0}$.